# Calculate the count and put in the same matrix table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, daxstudio

Data here:

[image]

What I expect to see: I want to sum the value for each member and approving person to put in the same row. For example: Maria was the an approving person who has 2 paperworks under review and 1 paperwork under in the office. I want to put combine the value that Maria had in the same table as the staff.

[image]

I would like to know how I write the query to support my work for SSRS. I tried:

```vb
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Staff.Value \<\> Fields!Approving_Person.Value, Fields!Staff.Value, Nothing))
```

I know the query wasn't right, would you please help me with this? I am not sure I need to have public code to make the table I need works.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be much easier in your dataset query.

If you use something like this

```
SELECT Staff, CurrentStatus 
    FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ApprovingPerson, CurrentStatus 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE ApprovingPerson IS NOT NULL
```

Then you will get a single list of Staff and Status which you can then easily build a matrix from.